# How to get data from multi table in data-config of Solr

Tags: java, mysql, solr, lucene, spring-data

I'm using Spring-Data-Solr, I have three tables and try get all data from those tables. this is relationship of table:

Car table:

```
      ID, NAME, PRICE, DISTRICT_ID(FK), CITY_ID(FK)
```

District table:

```
      ID(PK), DISTRICT_NAME
```

City table:

```
      ID(PK), CITY_NAME
```

in data-config.xml I try get all data and records in Car table with sql following as:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:/temp/example/ex" user="sa" />
<document>
    <entity name="city" query="select * from city">
        <field column="id" name="city_id" />
        <field column="name" name="city_name" />

        <entity name="cars" query="select * from cars where city_id='${city.id}'">
                <field column="id" name="id" />
                <field column="name" name="name" />
            <entity name="district" query="select * from district where id = '${cars.district_id}'">
                <field column="id" name="district_id" />
                <field column="name" name="district_name" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

When I execute on Solr Admin I just received 2 records, although in my car table have 11 records.

How to get all(11 records) in Car table? thanks

Comment: <entity name="district" query="select * from district where id = '${cars.district_id}'"> should have cars.id...or cars.district_id?

Comment: Hi, @AbhijitBashetti: thanks, can you tell me more detail..

Comment: did it worked for you? Whats details do you want to share ? instead of mutilple queries can you have a single query with join...

Comment: I have used join and it worked, thanks

Comment: Shall I mark/add it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"  url="jdbc:hsqldb:/temp/example/ex" user="sa" />
<document>
<entity name="city" query="select City.city_id ,City.city_name ,car.id ,car.name ,District.id  from Car join City on city.id = car.CITY_ID join District on car.DISTRICT_ID = District.id ">
    <field column="cityid" name="City.city_id" />
    <field column="cityname" name="City.city_name" />
    <field column="carid" name="car.id" />
    <field column="carname" name="car.name" />
    <field column="Districtid" name="District.id" />
    <etc... any column you need>


</entity>
</document>
```

**Edit**

Or you can Do Query in view [**TempView**]
AND configuration will be

```
<entity name="city" query="select * from TempView ">
    <field column="cityid" name="City.city_id" />
    <field column="cityname" name="City.city_name" />
    <field column="carid" name="car.id" />
    <field column="carname" name="car.name" />
    <field column="Districtid" name="District.id" />
    <etc... any column you need>


</entity>
</document>
```